# Bins + Totals By Rows - "cannot turn on grand totals for discrete measures"

Tags: tableau-api

I used a calculated field to create bins but because it's based on conditionals I'm unable to add my own totals.  Because of that, I tried using Grand Totals.  While it works, I cannot have discrete fields in the view.  This is an issue because I need a way to exclude rows I don't want to see - specifically I want to limit the view to the top N.

To limit it to top N, I just created a "rank" field using "index()" but it's a discrete measure.   I tried some other methods but it's always the same error.  Besides hiding it with blank tile, I don't know how else to remove the rows.

I won't be able to share the workbook or data but hoping someone has dealt with the issue and knows how to deal with it.

Note:  I've also posted this in Tableau's forum but no response there.

Comment: Have you tried using Tableau's built-in Top N filter?  Drag the thing you want to see the top N of (e.g. Customer Name) onto the Filter shelf, choose the "Top" tab, select "By field:", and then take the Top N by your desired ranking (e.g. "Sales $").

Comment: I haven't.   I'll have a look.  I just remember that I needed to use index for most of my ranking needs but don't remember why I stuck with that.  I'll have a look though in a little bit

Comment: I tried this but didn't work.  While it seems like it does, it doesn't seem to know how to handle bins.  It seems to ignore the ones that are actually ranked in the bottom two and push up others into the top 10